# How to do Bulk Insert using MySQL (like SqlBulkCopy) with Linq to Entities

Tags: mysql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity

Hi I need a method to insert a large number of records into a MySQL database table.

I'm using Linq to Entities and the method of using a foreach loop and inserting each record is too slow.

e.g.

```
foreach(var item in items){
    context.Add(item);
    context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Is there a method like the MySql command: LOAD DATA INFILE available in the .net connector?

Answer (score 3):

Entity framework (and Linq-to-entities) has no support for bulk inserts. Bulk inserts must always be done through native features of database server. To use `LOAD DATA INFILE` from .NET Connector check [`MySqlBulkLoader` class](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-programming-bulk-loader.html).

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. Shame MySql haven't got a better option.

Answer (score -1):

This post looks promising. I'm giving it a try in my own application. Plus, it doesn't interfere with your designer since it is a partial class.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/297582/Using-bulk-insert-with-your-linq-to-sql-datacontex

In addition, here's a class on MSDN that does the same thing:

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/LinqEntityDataReader

I've reimplemented the function in this SO post:

[bulk insert with linq-to-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220901/bulk-insert-with-linq-to-sql/11974858#11974858)