# Importing large text file into sql database

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, insertonsubmit

I read txt files and saving rows from this file to local database.The Problem is that program reads 700 000 rows and it takes long time to read whole file. I use linq to sql, firs I read the row, then i split it in to the Table object and then I submit into DB.

For example The row has format

```
2014-03-01 00:08:02.380 00000000000001100111
```

this row is splited into DateTime and 20 columns (each column represents 1 channel (CH1 - CH20))

Is there a better (faster) way?

Comment: show your current code, how can we offer you a better way without seeing the code you are using currently ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the FileHelpers http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/ to feed directly into SqlBulkCopy. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx
That is by far the easiest and fastest approach.

You can still use Linq-2-sql for read/non-batch writes but for bulkinsert is is simply too slow.

Answer (score 0):

That would be slow with linq to sql submitting that many items. 
Bulk insert or Bulk update would be preferable for this task which you can't with linq to sql. See also this post. [bulk insert with linq-to-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220901/bulk-insert-with-linq-to-sql)

I suggest something else than linq to sql for this task.

Comment: Thank you very much, If i understood correctly, I must read the whole file and than i insert whole file to the database. I need between this two steps split rows to datetime and 20 columns represents each channel. How do I do? (sorry i do not speek english well)