# Bulk insert using LINQ

Tags: linq, bulkinsert

Let's say we want to insert some data from one table to another in SQL. We would do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tableY
SELECT name, type, <other fields>
FROM tableX;
```

Here we can conveniently omit the ID from tableX being inserted to tableY, if it's an auto-generated column.

How would you do that in LINQ? I know you can get a list of items from tableX and iterate and do that. But can we do that using a single LINQ Query, without iterating?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Linq to Entities does not provide a way to that. You can check in here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9221551/1384539

On the same thread, there's a suggestion to do that, I hope it could help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11974858/1384539